# Configure Dynamic TCP Server to send message to the client connected Spring Integration using Java DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to create a Integration flow :

`Connection A :  [ ActiveMq (queue1) ---> TCP Server (1111) ](spring boot Application)  ---> [ExternalApplication (client connected to Server running on port (1111))] (Application on different Technology (VB))`

`Connection B :  [ ActiveMq (queue2) ---> TCP Server (2222) ](spring boot Application)  ---> [ExternalApplication (client connected to Server running on port (2222))] (Application on different Technology (VB))`

So Above flow depicts following scenario:

1. I have a spring boot application (say springUtility) which connect with external application(say externalutility) on some other technology.
2. The connection between springutility and externalUtility is through TCP protocol.
3. There will be more than one connection between both the utilities as in above flow diagram connection A and connection B.
4. The flow of message will be from springUtilty to externalutility (One way)
5. Now, the externalutility can run in client Mode or server mode. so, if the externalUtility run in server Mode then my springutility will be in client mode (Done) also to create more than one connection I run this below code in for loop code :

Code:

```
flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.inboundAdapter(ConnectionFactory())
                    .destination("rec"))
                    .channel(directChannel()).handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(Tcp.nioClient("172.18.11.22",5555)
                             .serializer(customSerializer)
                             .deserializer(customSerializer)
                             .id(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber()).soTimeout(10000)))
                            .get();

    flowRegistration = this.flowContext.registration(flow).id("in.flow").register();
```

6. Issue : When the externalutility run in client mode then spring utility should able to create a server on which the external utility will get connected and then it start receiving messsages from spring utility:
   which I tried to implement in a wrong way.
7. So, finally I have to Implement the above connection as a test case to validate the flow,
   means spring utility has opened server port (1111 and 2222) the external application connect with these two port and start receiving the message from spring utility from queue1 and queue2 repectively. Both the connection will have there seperate flow (Once a single flow will be created then we can use a for loop to create no of connection we need).

Code:

```
flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.inboundAdapter(ConnectionFactory())
                    .destination("rec"))
                    .channel(directChannel()).handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(Tcp.netServer(5555)
                             .serializer(customSerializer)
                             .deserializer(customSerializer)
                             .id(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber()).soTimeout(10000)))
                            .get();

    flowRegistration = this.flowContext.registration(flow).id("in.flow").register();
```

`
code:

```
2018-05-30 17:39:39.171  INFO 15776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {jms:outbound-channel-adapter} as a subscriber to the 'Conn1311out.flow.channel#0' channel
2018-05-30 17:39:39.172  INFO 15776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.Conn1311out.flow.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2018-05-30 17:39:39.172  INFO 15776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3
2018-05-30 17:39:41.965  INFO 15776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter} as a subscriber to the 'Conn1311in.flow.channel#0' channel
2018-05-30 17:39:41.965  INFO 15776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.Conn1311in.flow.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2018-05-30 17:39:41.966  INFO 15776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : started Conn1311, port=3333
2018-05-30 17:39:41.966  INFO 15776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#4
2018-05-30 17:39:41.966  INFO 15776 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : Conn1311, port=3333 No listener bound to server connection factory; will not read; exiting...
2018-05-30 17:39:41.971  INFO 15776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : started org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0
```

It first create the server on the provided port but exit with following message

`No listener bound to server connection factory; will not read; exiting...`

When I am creating the client it is working fine but in case of creating server it is giving error

EDIT:

I have use the following approach to create dynamically different server and send message to connected client from its respective activemq client

1. I have created an inbound adapter as below :

   ```
   IntegrationFlow flow;
   CustomSerializer customSerializer = getCustomSerializer(String.valueOf(hostConnection.getMaxMessageLength()),
           hostConnection.getTerminatorChar());

   TcpSendingMessageHandler handler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
   TcpNetServerConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(1234));
   cf.setSerializer(customSerializer);
   cf.setDeserializer(customSerializer);
   handler.setConnectionFactory(cf);

        flow = IntegrationFlows
           .from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(cf).id("adapter")).handle(handler)
           .get();

        this.flowContext.registration(flow).id("inflow")
        .addBean(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber(),cf)
        .addBean(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber()+"handler",handler)
        .register();
   ```
2. I have created a Jmsflow in which the message from the queue is send to a router as below:

   ```
       flow = IntegrationFlows
           .from(Jms.inboundAdapter(activeMQConnectionFactory)
           .destination(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber() +"rec")) 
           .channel(directChannel()).route(new ServerRouter())
           .get();
   ```
3. when the client got connected to my server then I create a flow from the listener `handleTcpConnectionCloseEvent(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event)` and create a flow as:

   ```
   void createServerFlow(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event) {
       String connectionNumber = event.getConnectionFactoryName();
       TcpNetConnection server = (TcpNetConnection) event.getSource();
       TcpSendingMessageHandler handler = (TcpSendingMessageHandler) ac.getBean(connectionNumber + "handler");

       IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.enrichHeaders(e -> e.header(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, event.getConnectionId()))
               .handle(handler);
       IntegrationFlowRegistration flowregister = this.flowContext.registration(flow).id("outclient").register();

       MessageChannel channel = flowregister.getInputChannel();

       this.subFlows.put(connectionNumber + "server", channel);
   }
   ```
4. My ServerRouter find the channel and send to the target channel

   ```
   protected Collection<MessageChannel> determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message) {
   String serverChannel = (String) message.getHeaders().get("connectionnumber");
   MessageChannel channel = HostConnectionRepository.subFlows
           .get(serverChannel+"server");

   return Collections.singletonList(channel);
   ```

   }
5. when I got disconnected then I remove the flow from flowContext created in `step 3`.

**Issue :** 
When I remove the flow the bean associated with the flow also get removed as its written in the docs that related beans will also discard.

This remove my handler bean which close the TCP adapter also the connectionfactory hence once it get disconnected it can't connect again

How can i discard the outclientflow without discarding the handler bean?

Comment: These are the required log In case if anybody needs complete log. Please comment.

Comment: There are no **complete log**. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The `Tcp.outboundAdapter()` is not a `TcpListener`. It is just sender to the TCP socket. That's why you get that exception.

If we talk about TCP server, it must be a listener, an Inbound Endpoint.

It is fully unclear why would one create a TCP server dynamically on the send operation...

You need to re-think your logic and have such a TCP server for listening really outside of this dynamic logic. And here would use only a client variant to send TCP packets to the required TCP port.

Comment: There is some external application which can either run in client mode or in server mode if the external application is running in server mode the I create the following flow by giving connection factory details of client, but If the external application behave as a client the I have to configure a Server so that the external application can connect to it

Comment: Correct. So, this TCP server has to be configured in advance, before you start creating flows dynamically. Currently there is no any TCP listeners in your solution.

Comment: Limitation in creating TCP Server in advance that in my application I don't know how many servers I have to create it should be create on runtime

Comment: That's something wrong... If it is *client*, then it has to know where to connect and you share with it your server port. The client can't dictate what to do on the server. You have to re-think an architecture. You can create servers dynamically, but that's already not a `Tcp.outboundAdapter()` responsibility. You need to start a separate `IntegrationFlow` for server listener and reuse the `ConnectionFactory` from there.

Comment: I think i am not able to explain my issue clearly, please see the below link [link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/746570-send-message-from-server-connection-factory-to-the-client) this is what i want but I want to do this at runtime   with above flow i.e the mesage received from activemq is send to the client connected to my server created dynamically

Comment: I have updated the question Hope this time you can understand what is my requirement.

Comment: Well, as I said you before: you need to create a single server connection factory and all the clients have t oconnect to the same server port. For that purpose you need to configure a `Tcp.inboundAdapter()` based on the `Tcp.netServer()`. When you receive a message via this channel adapter, you get a `IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID` header to be able to distinguish your clients connected. At this point you really can create a dynamic flow for currently connected client and perform send via `TcpSendingMessageHandler` and that server connection factory reference.

Comment: I have used an approach for this but there is an issue please see the issue i have edited the question

Comment: You found answer in the Docs by yourself: once an `IntegrationFlow` is destroyed, all the associated beans are destroyed as well. There is no other way. What is the question? That's how things work that's all. Once you reconnect you have to recreate the whole `IntegrationFlow`. I don't say that your approach is right, but since you insist on your solution we can't do anything for you. Absolutely not clear why would one did such a solution using dynamic structures: everything sounds like some stable singleton beans.

Comment: Maybe would be better if you start from scratch and rethink an approach? Or even consider do not use Spring Integration on the matter...

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do; clients normally initiate connections, not offer a port for others to connect to.

Even if somebody connects to that port, the client won't know which socket to send the message to. So you will get errors at runtime.

> No listener bound to server connection factory; will not read; exiting...

That message is simply saying there is no component registered with the factory to receive incoming messages.

Comment: Sorry if I am not able to clearly explain the question `Activemq ---> TCP server      ---->           External Application(Client Mode responsible to connect to my TCP server)`    , hence I have to create a server and when the client got connected to my server then I have to send the message This link might help you to understand [question](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/746570-send-message-from-server-connection-factory-to-the-client) if you want I can edit the question

Comment: Your current flow is incorrect for that scenario; it will try to send data regardless of whether a client is connected and, in any case, even if there is a client, you need to set the connection id header so the outbound adapter knows where to send it. You need something like `tcpInbound->customService->tcpoutbound`.

Comment: thanks for the response  Do I have to create a seperate integrationfIow for `tcpInbound ->customservice-->outbound'  both the adapter will have server cf and how I will add this configuration in my above flow .

Comment: You need a new flow; you can't add it to that flow; as I said, it is invalid.

Comment: how do I link these two different flow ? Is there any resource or code snippet where I can take an idea how to implement the required flow

Comment: Your requirements are incomplete. For example, what do you want to do if 2 clients connect? Is it a queue or a topic? Perhaps you can edit your question to show your **actual** requirements and then somebody might be able to help you move forward. I might be able to take a look tomorrow.

Comment: updated the question with actual requirement hope you understand my requirement.